# Take data from one table and store it into another

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger that will take any any daily_rate that is over 15 and put it into a new table known as valuable_item. I have already created the new table and so all I need is to carry over the required data. Below is the code I have tried within the trigger edit section:

```
INSERT INTO valuable_items (catalogue_id,
description,
designer,
type,
daily_rate)
VALUES 
(new.catalogue_id,
new.description,
new.designer,
new.type,
new.daily_rate, WHERE daily_rate >= 15
```

Comment: You stated your objective and your solution but not your problem

Comment: apologies that would help! The trigger works without the WHERE statement, however when I add this it creates an error and will not populate my table

Comment: What error are you getting? Is it not working? You stated what you tried, but didn't ask a question.

Comment: You need to remove the where. And add a closing ). Place the entire query inside an IF block to test new.daily_rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF new.daily_rate >= 15 THEN
    INSERT INTO valuable_items (
        catalogue_id,
        description,
        designer,
        type,
        daily_rate)
    VALUES 
    (new.catalogue_id,
    new.description,
    new.designer,
    new.type,
    new.daily_rate);
END IF;
```

Comment: Thank you, absolute legend!!

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are looking for this, for within the trigger:

```
IF new.daily_rate >= 15 THEN 
    INSERT INTO valuable_items (catalogue_id,
    description,
    designer,
    type,
    daily_rate)
    VALUES 
    (new.catalogue_id,
    new.description,
    new.designer,
    new.type,
    new.daily_rate);
END IF;
```